# Serialization of AutomationElement

Tags: c#, serialization, automation, datacontractserializer

Is there any way to serialize `AutomationElement` object and write it to file using `DataContractSerializer`?

I use `UIAutomation Com Wrapper` and I could try to add [serializable] tags to every element of library, but I'm afraid that it's not gonna work.

Right now I have kAutomationElement field in my custom serializable object but when it comes to writing it, it says that members must be serializable as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AutomationElement is a sealed class.  You can't sublass it or add attributes to existing elements.

The DataContractSerializer is expecting... a DataContract! (the attributes).

So, you won't be able to use DataContractSerializer.
BUT... I don't think there is anything preventing you from using [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)

If you are trying to persist state to disk, binary might be your only choice, unless you create your own serializable class and map the AutomationElement object to it manually.

OR... if you simply want to skip serializing the kAutomationelement, add the [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx)